# Is there a way to run go test for only one file?

Tags: go

I checked documentation and help tutorial. Didn't find answer.

I just want to run a_test.go not all *_test.go.
Is this possible or how?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out `go test -test.run`. It takes a regex and runs only the test functions whose suffixes match the regex (with the suffix defined as the thing after "Test" so "XXX" in "TestXXX").

Comment: this is great. thanks @synful Just don't know why doesn't go documantation mention this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Command Documentation](http://golang.org/doc/cmd)
>
> [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [Description of testing flags](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags)
>
> The following flags are recognized by the 'go test' command and
>   control the execution of any test:
>
> ```
> -run regexp
>     Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
>     expression.
> ```

To run the tests which satisfy the regex regular expression:

```
go test -run=regexp
```